# How to make sure that the linear span of vectors is the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Suppose that we have $p$ linearly independent vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_p\in\mathbb R^n$ such that each of these vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of orthogonal vectors $z_1,\ldots,z_p\in\mathbb R$. I am trying to show that the subspaces spanned by $x_1,\ldots,x_p$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_p$ are the same.

$z_1,\ldots,z_p$ span the subspace spanned by the vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_p\in\mathbb R^n$ because $x_1,\ldots,x_p$ can be expressed as linear combinations of $z_1,\ldots,z_p$. What could be the argument we could use to make sure that $z_1,\ldots,z_p$ cannot span a larger subspace? It seems that a proof by contradiction is the way to go but I am not sure how to proceed.

This is question is related to the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: As written, your statement is not true. The only thing you can say is that $\text{Span}\{x_1,...,x_p\}\subset \text{Span}\{z_1,...,z_p\}$. The converse inequality is true if furthermore $\{x_1,...,x_p\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @Surb Thanks a lot for the comment! I will modify the question and add that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_p\}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: **Hint:** Then, these two spaces have the same dimension.